# “Error while retrieving information from server [DF-DFERH-01]” on Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, system-error

I have a Storex eZee Tab 702 tablet. My Google Play Store was working very well until a few weeks ago, when it started saying,

> Error while retrieving information from server [DF-DFERH-01]

I tried to clear the cache, clear the data, force stop, and downloading another Google Play Store, but I'm still having the same problem.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Please take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812822/google-play-error-error-while-retrieving-information-from-server-df-dferh-01
and: http://androidforums.com/android-lounge/590061-error-while-retrieving-information-server-df-dferh-01-help.html.

Answer (score 0):

for android 5.0

1. Go to "SETTINGS"
2. Click "GENERAL TAB"
3. Scroll down and click "Application Manager"
4. Scroll across to "ALL"
5. Scroll down to and click "Google Play Store"
6. Click "CLEAR DATA"
7. Go back and now open "PLAY STORE"